# `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Datagrid::Filters (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid

I have old Rails app which works before Rails 4.11.2. Now when i try to deploy is latest Rails it show me error when i run

$ sudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0

is show: /home/deploy/project/config/initializers/datagrid/filters/date_time_filter.rb:2:in `': uninitialized constant Datagrid::Filters (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with `bundle exec` it by `sudo bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0`.
You probably shouldn't use sudo to run rails app.

Comment: yes i use sudo bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 and also bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 but not work.

Answer (score 0):

/home/deploy/project/config/initializers/datagrid/filters/date_time_filter.rb:2:in
You are missing something like vairable  environment value or some file path needed to run this file required to load the configuration  to start the server.